# How to detect an iFrame in Xpages

Tags: iframe, xpages

I'm trying to render a panel depending on if the xpage is loaded in an iFrame or not.

My code looks something like this

```
<xp:panel
    rendered="#{javascript:return window.self != window.top;}">
</xp:panel>
```

But I'm getting an error.

```
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=20: [ReferenceError] 'window' not found
-> 1: return window.self !== window.top;
```

Am I on the right track or is there another way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rendered=` code in your panel gets executed on **server side** and therefore `window` is not available.

Execute your code on client side and hide element(s) if page is not loaded in an iFrame.

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
          if (window == window.top) {
              document.getElementById("#{id:panel1}").style.display = 'none';
          }]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:text
        id="computedField1"
        value="#{javascript:'test'}">
    </xp:text>
</xp:panel>
```

---

In case you don't want to render and later hide the iFrame-only part you can use an other approach:

- render the page without the iFrame-only part first
- if client recognizes that page is loaded in an iFrame

  - execute a partial refresh for iFrame-only panel with an URL parameter `iFrame=yes`
  - memorize that iFrame-only panel shall be rendered in a viewScope variable on server side

This is a working example XPage for this approach

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            if (window != window.top) {
                XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:panel1}", {
                    params: { 
                        'iFrame': 'yes'
                    }
                });
            }]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:panel
        id="panel1">
        <xp:panel
            id="panel2"
            rendered="#{javascript: 
              if (param.iFrame) {viewScope.iFrame = param.iFrame}; viewScope.iFrame}">
            <xp:text
                id="computedField1"
                value="#{javascript:'test'}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Tnx Knut, just the input I needed